# Rendering array list that's stored in a Collection in Meteor

Tags: meteor

In my User collection, I have an array called `synonym_ids`.

What's the easiest way to show this on the client?

I tried publishing the following from the server and then subscribing from the client. However I get this error:

`Internal exception while starting subscription 0ea473b6-8be4-43ec-8a56-988409a4b58a Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions.`

```
#server
Meteor.publish 'synonym_ids', () ->
    if Meteor.userId()
        return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()}).synonym_ids


#client
Meteor.autosubscribe () ->
    Meteor.subscribe 'synonym_ids'
```

Comment: Have you tried to replace Meteor.userId() by this.UserId?

Comment: @Oscar, so how would I surface this to a template?

Comment: @Oscar is right:  change `if Meteor.userId()` to `if this.userId`.  I think you might also need to return a cursor from the publsh function or do something more advanced.  Try `return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},{fields:{synonym_ids: 1}})` to make sure the user sees that field.  Then on the client, once the subscription finishes, you should be able to access `synonym_ids` with `Meteor.user().synonym_ids`.

Comment: @zorlak, doing `return Meteor.user().synonym_ids` from a Template helper isn't working.

Comment: Ok, can you post the code that isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A publish function [can't use Meteor.userId()](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_userid), but it can use [this.userId](http://docs.meteor.com/#publish_userId)

```
#server
Meteor.publish 'synonym_ids', () ->
if this.userId()
    return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId()}).synonym_ids
```

In your template helper be sure to check whether the user is logged in:

```
#client
Template.home.synonym_ids = ->
   Meteor.user().synonym_ids  if Meteor.userId
```